# node.js Failed @ at the production script

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm

Seems to be an error when running npm run prod
Cant seem to figure it out and have spent hours this is my last resort . Can someone help thanks

```
<i>
[webpack-cli] Error: Unknown option '--no-progress'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ production: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Failed at the @ production script.
npm ERR! @ prod: `npm run production`
```

Error log

```
7 verbose lifecycle @~prod: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~prod: PATH: /root/.nvm/versions/node/v11.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/var/www/test/node_modules/.bin:/root/.nvm/versions/node/v11.15.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle @~prod: CWD: /var/www/test
10 silly lifecycle @~prod: Args: [ '-c', 'npm run production' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~prod: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~prod: Failed to exec prod script
13 verbose stack Error: @ prod: `npm run production`
13 verbose stack Exit status 2
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v11.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:193:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v11.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:193:13)
14 verbose pkgid @
16 verbose Linux 5.4.0-89-generic
17 verbose argv "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v11.15.0/bin/node" "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v11.15.0/bin/npm" "run" "prod"
18 verbose node v11.15.0
19 verbose npm  v6.7.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 2
22 error @ prod: `npm run production`
22 error Exit status 2
23 error Failed at the @ prod script.
```

Comment: Can you share your package.json and your scripts field

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.